# Unexpected Clickhouse datetime results

Tags: sql, datetime, select, where-clause, clickhouse

I'm transferring data from one clickhouse server to another one and faced problem with data filtering and timezone doesn't look correct. For simplicity lets call these servers server A and server B.

---

Server A has following response for time functions : timezone() = Europe/Moscow  , now() = 2023-04-13 10:39:25
Server B returns same data for these functions.
Both servers actually do not return Europe/Moscow time , they return UTC time (2023-04-13 10:39:25 is UTC and 2023-04-13 13:39:25 is correct Europe/Moscow time

---

Server A table has following timeseries column - _timestamp (DateTime64(3))
Server B table has following timeseries column - _timestamp (DateTime64(3))

---

I'm transfering data like following

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE B (LIST OF CLUMNS)
SELECT
(LIST OF COLUMNS)
from remote('server A',databasenameA.tablenameA,'user','password')
where _timestamp >= '2022-09-01 00:00:00' and _timestamp < '2023-02-01 00:00:00'
```

Actually this script takes data in range >= '2022-08-31 21:00:00' and < '2023-01-31 21:00:00'

I can prove this if i take min and max date in target table after loading
select min(`_timestamp`) from  TABLE_A = 2022-08-31 21:00:00
select max(`_timestamp`) from  TABLE_A = 2023-01-31 20:59:59

---

Why despite on correct timezone() = Europe/Moscow i receive incorrect datetime (actually UTC time).
Why despite on filtering conditions >= '2022-09-01 00:00:00' and  < '2023-02-01 00:00:00' clickhouse convert these date conditions to another values.
I'm using DBeaver to run these stateements and do not have direct access to server machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query table like this

```
select min(_timestamp) from TABLE_A
```

You get a value rendered into the text by DBeaver. It's not the orignal datetime timestamp, but the UInt32 value converted to Text by JVM using your current timezone at your desktop.

I suggest to use `toUnixTimestamp` to avoid confusion.

```
select toUnixTimestamp(min(_timestamp)) as min_timestamp from TABLE_A
```

And use that `min_timestamp` as a filter predicate in the `INSERT SELECT`.

Comment: Thank you , but why when I call timezone() this returns correct time zone but when I call now() this returns -3 hours from correct date (on any of related servers A or B)

Comment: compare `select now() x, toString(now()) y`. `x` is rendered into text by DBeaver, `y` by CH server.